# Problem with printing of cases statement on overview

Tags: bug, mathjax, frontpage

I just noticed that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664489/marginal-probabilities) question has some printing issues on the overview page that has to do with a `\begin{cases}` statement.

[image: problematic appearance]

Comment: Unless it has been changed, the reason is that the code for the preview grabs the first $n$ characters of the post. That of course provides ample opportunities to get broken MathJax code for the preview.

Comment: @DanielFischer But the strange looking box shouldn't be desirable, I think.

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20055) seems related. I think we have a question about the excerpt preview with an answer, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Also [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13835/excerpts-in-search-results-breaks-mathjax-fragments), which links to [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/formatting-in-the-search-results-page-breaks-when-the-query-contains-certain-ter). These are about search results, but it's probably the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the problem is that MathJax syntax is chopped. This happens all the time, and usually results in completely non-rendered partial formula, which I think is the best we are going to have for a long time.

Another problem is that the text did have enough of a formula in it to render somewhat, resulting in an ugly box. This has to do with nested markup (and somewhat sloppy at that):

```
  $f_{XY}(x,y) =  \begin{cases}
          2e^{-y} & \text{if  $-y< x < y$ and 0 < y < } \infty .\\
      0 & ...
```

I edited it to remove formula-text-formula nesting:

```
 \text{if  } -y< x < y \ \text{ and }\ 0 < y < \infty
```

Now the preview has plain unrendered formula, since there is no $ for MathJax to interpret as the closing delimiter.

---

Part of a problem is having symmetric delimiters `$ ... $`, which was not the best idea for TeX... Today one is advised to use `\( \)` in LaTeX documents but this doesn't work   well here due to escaping and over-escaping.